# Vector bundles on curves and Adeles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, arithmetic-geometry

I have heard of the following 'well-known' result attributed to Weil, that rank $ n $ vector bundles on a curves over a field can be obtained as double quotients of $ \operatorname{GL}_n $ of the Adeles.

Can someone expound on this construction, or point to a reference?

Comment: The idea is roughly clear: any vector bundle $\mathcal{E}$ on $C$ is trivial on $C-\{p_1,\ldots,p_n\}$ for some points $p_i$. By Beauville--Laszlo gluing one can think of $\mathcal{E}$ as roughly gluing the trivial bundles over each $\widehat{\mathcal{O}}_{C,p_i}$ with the trivial bundle on $C-\{p_1,\ldots,p_n\}$. Thinking through what such gluing data looks like, modding out by choices made, and considering the varying over all points $\{p_i\}$ arrives at your statement (roughly).

Comment: Some keypoints to google are 'affine Grassmannian'. For instance, this is somewhat discussed here: https://math.berkeley.edu/~fengt/Zhu.pdf I can find a better reference later if you would like it.

Comment: I answered the question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4786176/404616.