# Is this example of 1-dimensional geometric class field theory correct?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, class-field-theory

I'm trying to understand the main theorem of geometric class field theory. Could someone tell me if this example is correct?

**Main theorem.** Let $K$ be a function field of a curve over a finite field. There is a bijection between unramified $\ell$-adic Galois representations of $G_K := \operatorname{Gal}(K^{sep}/K)$ and $\ell$-adic characters of $K^{\times}\backslash\mathbf{A}_K^{\times}/\mathcal{O}_K^{\times}.$ (Here I mean the ideles modulo the diagonal on the left, and on the right quotiented by the subgroup of ideles which have non-negative valuation at every place.)

I was trying to understand what this means when $K = \mathbb{F}_p(T),$ say. In that case, I think unramified Galois representations are the same as representations of $\operatorname{Gal}(K^{un}/K) = \operatorname{Gal}(\overline{\mathbf{F}_p}(T)/\mathbf{F}_p(T))= \hat{\mathbf{Z}}.$

--

On the other side, I believe that I can simplify that double quotient as follows. The places of $K$ are described as follows: there is one place with uniformizer $1/T,$ and then for every monic irreducible polynomial $f(T) \in \mathbb{F}_p[T],$ there is a place with uniformizer $f.$ These are distinct places, and every place is of one of these two forms.

There is a surjective map $\mathbf{A}_K^{\times}\to \bigoplus_{v\in P} \mathbf{Z},$ for $P$ the set of places of $K,$ sending an idele to its valuation at each place. The kernel is precisely $\mathcal{O}_K^{\times},$ and so $$\mathbf{A}_K^{\times}/\mathcal{O}_K^{\times} \cong \bigoplus_{v\in P} \mathbf{Z}.$$

The diagonal embedding of $K^{\times}$ then corresponds to the subgroup of $\bigoplus_{v\in P}\mathbf{Z}$ consisting of elements whose sum is $0.$ In particular, the quotient by the diagonal subgroup leaves us with just $\mathbf{Z}.$

As a sanity check, $\operatorname{Pic}(\mathbb{P}^1) = \mathbf{Z},$ as found in any book on algebraic geometry, and I believe part of the proof of geometric class field goes by identifying the double quotient with the Picard group, so it makes sense we got $\mathbf{Z}$ here.

--

So, I think that in this case, it is telling me that continuous homomorphisms $\rho : \hat{\mathbf{Z}} \to \overline{\mathbf{Q}_{\ell}}^{\times}$ are in bijection with continuous homomorphisms $\mathbf{Z}\to \overline{\mathbf{Q}_{\ell}}^{\times}.$

But this surely is incorrect -- the image of a map out of the profinite integers must be compact, but the image out of $\mathbf{Z}$ is not.

So, where have I made a mistake?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Unless I'm wrong: an image out of $\mathbf{Z}$ is the same as just an element of $K^{\times}.$ Pick some $p$-adic integer which has positive $p$-adic valuation; then the powers of that integer go to infinity -- so not only is the image not compact, but the image is not contained in any compact set.

Comment: Ah, I was thinking the target was profinite. In that case I don't know enough to comment, sorry.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan No worries! Thank you for replying!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4661828/vector-bundles-on-curves-and-adeles

Comment: ^i asked this question but got no response. I believe your comment about the double quotient being the Picard group generalizes to vector bundles in my question. Do you know anything about this?

Comment: You need to work with the Weil group instead of the whole Galois group, then your problem doesn't appear

Comment: (Note that I learned global CFT in another formulation, so my comment might miss the mark)

Comment: @LukasHeger I am not sure -- the source I am reading states for the Galois group, not Weil group.

Comment: Where did you find your main theorem?

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim See theorem 2.8 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.00104.pdf

Comment: It is not a problem that the image of $\hat{\Bbb{Z}}$ should be compact and $\Bbb{Z}$ not so. The bijection should be given by the canonical inclusion $\Bbb{Z}\to \hat{\Bbb{Z}}$, and then use that the image is dense, then continuity. However, your first comment is indeed cause for concern. Normally, the image of a character of a profinite group would lie in the $p$-adic units. My guess is that the paper is a little too loose with its topologies, and you really need to retopologize something or the other, or add another condition, to get this correspondence.

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim Ahh -- so you're saying that: maps $\hat{\mathbf{Z}} \to K^{\times}$ (for $K$ this closure of $\ell$-adic numbers) are in bijection with $\ell$-adic units. The paper I am reading gives the wrong definition of character, and the *correct* definition would be to say that the image of a character lands in the $\ell$-adic units?

Comment: @LukasHeger Thank you! It seems like the paper I was learning from just defined characters incorrectly, and there should have been some compactness assumption...

Comment: @oggledog yeah, in fancy language, you want automorphic representations and not just any representation. I deleted the comment because I'm unsure about the $\overline{\Bbb Q}_\ell$ coefficients vs. $\overline{\Bbb Q}$ coefficients. But some automorphy/compactness assumption should be included regardless

Comment: Note that it is true that $G_K^{ab}$ and $\operatorname{Pic}(X)$ (or that adelic double quotient) have the same profinite completions and $\operatorname{Pic}(X)$ is always isomorphic to the abelianized Weil group. So another way to "save" the correspondence would be either to include a profinite completion or to replace the Galois group with a Weil group