# Vector Bundles on a Curve as an Adelic Double Quotient

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, algebraic-curves, adeles

I'm looking for an explanation or a reference on why rank $n$ vector bundles on a curve over a field can be described as $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathcal O)\backslash \mathrm{GL}_n(\Bbb A)/\mathrm{GL}_n(K)$, where $K$ is the function field of the curve, $\Bbb A$ is the corresponding ring of adeles and $\mathcal O\subset \Bbb A$ is the subring of integral adeles.

I'm aware of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/112593/adelic-description-of-moduli-of-g-bundles-on-a-curve) and its answers, but it seems overkill for this special case.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4661828/vector-bundles-on-curves-and-adeles

Asked the same question, got nothing useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $V$ be a rank $n$ vector bundle over $X$. Then $V$ is trivial on a dense open subset $U=X\backslash S$ of $X$. Let $f\colon V\to \mathcal O_X^n$ be a meromorphic isomorphism (i.e., an isomorphism on $U$). Now for each $x\in X$ the map $f$ gives rise to a $\mathcal O_x$-linear map $V_x\hookrightarrow K_x^n$ which realizes $V_x$ as a $\mathcal O_x$-lattice of rank $n$. This can be viewed as an element $[V_x]\in\mathrm{GL}_n(K_x)/\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathcal O_x)$. Moreover, for $x\in U$ this element is trivial. This exactly defines an element in $\prod_{x\in X}[V_x]\in\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb A)/\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathcal O)$. A different choice of the meromorphic isomorphism differs by an element $A\in\mathrm{GL}_n(K)$, so we actually obtain an element of $\mathrm{GL}_n(K)\backslash \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb A)/\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathcal O)$.

Conversely, given an element of $\mathrm{GL}_n(K)\backslash \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb A)/\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathcal O)$, by going back along the construction of the last paragraph, we obtain, for each $x\in X$, a $\mathcal O_x$-lattice $V_x\subset K_x^n$, such that for $x$ in a dense subset, the lattice $V_x$ is the standard one $\mathcal O_x^n$. Now, we can obtain a coherent vector bundle $V $ whose sections at $U\subset X$ is
$$\{f\in K^n:\forall x\in U,f_x\in V_x\}.$$
One can readily check that this defines a locally free $\mathcal O_X$-module of rank $n$ on $X$.

---

I will elaborate on what I mean by a meromorphic isomorphism, since I was asked to in the comments.

Let $V$ be be a vector bundle trivial on a dense open subset $U$ of $X$. Then we have an isomorphism $f\colon V|_U\to \mathcal O_U^n$. In particular, this induces an isomorphism $V_\zeta\simeq K^n$, where $V_\zeta$ is the stalk of $V$ at the generic point $\zeta$ of $X$, which is a $K=k(X)$-vector space of rank $n$. Now, there is a map $V_x\hookrightarrow V_\zeta\otimes_{k(X)}K_x\simeq K_x^n$, which is what I use in the rest of the answer.

Comment: How do you get f on $ X $?

Comment: Are you referring to the meromorphic isomorphism f between V and O^n?

Comment: Yes, I have never heard of this terminology - meromorphic isomorphism.

Comment: I just meant isomorphism on a dense open subset. This allows you to do everything in the answer.

Comment: But that doesn’t give you any map when x is outside U.

Comment: It gives a map $V_x\otimes_{\mathcal O_x}K_x\to \mathcal O_x^n\otimes_{\mathcal O_x}K_x=K_x^n$, which is what I'm claiming and using, even when $x\notin U$.

Comment: But you need a global f, which you don’t have. This is what I’ve been trying to say in my last three comments. There is no reason for a global map like f to exist.

Comment: Defining f on U suffices to provide the map in my previous comment.

Comment: Huh? This is getting senseless. There is no map from O(1) to O on P^1.

Comment: @CraniumClamp I have edited the answer.

Comment: (1) the residue field K_x is not even an extension of the function field k(X). (2) you still say that the map is induced by f, when there is no f. (3) if you’re calling others rude for pointing out obvious loopholes in your answer and more importantly, evading them with fancy words, I have nothing to add.

Comment: $K_x$ is not the residue field, it is the fraction field of the completed local ring $\mathcal O_x$. There is a map $f$ on the open dense subset, which induces an isomorphic on the generic stalk. There is always an embedding of the (non-completed) stalk $V_x$ into the generic stalk (by, e.g., looking at a different affine open neighborhood). Thus, after completing, there is an embedding to the generic stalk tensored up to $K_x$.